# Check if command exists

Tags: django

Is there any way to check if command exists?

I know that I can write:

```
try:
    call_command('some')
except:
    print "Command does not exists"
```

but maybe django allow to check if command is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`get_commands`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/__init__.py#L70):

```
from django.core.management import get_commands, call_command

if 'some_command' in get_commands():
    call_command('some_command')
```